# R - does `prcomp` take sample data or covariance matrices as input?

Tags: r, matrix

If you search online there are a few threads that discuss the use of the `covmat` flag in the function `princomp`, which performs principal component analysis on its input. If the `covmat` parameter is not defined, `princomp` first computes the sample covariance matrix of the input.

On the other hand, there is little to no discussion about what a similar function `prcomp` actually does to accomplish the task of principal component analysis on data, only discussions about whether or not it is more accurate than `princomp`. This begs the question: does `prcomp` take covariance matrices or sample data matrices as input? It's not clear from the help documentation, which states (in the non-formula context):

> ### Default S3 method:
>
> `prcomp(x, retx = TRUE, center = TRUE, scale. = FALSE,
>          tol = NULL, ...)`
>
> `x` - a numeric or complex matrix (or data frame) which provides the data for the principal components analysis.

The help file does not include any examples for this method, only an example for the one documented above it which works on formula objects. The documentation sort of implies that the expected input is a covariance matrix, like so:

> The calculation is done by a singular value decomposition of the (centered and possibly scaled) data matrix, not by using `eigen` on the covariance matrix.

However, it is unclear whether "data matrix" is a "covariance matrix", and whether or not "data matrix" means `x` as given in the earlier part of the documentation.

Comment: Reasons for the downvote? If it's a better fit for crossvalidated, that's one thing.

Comment: I did not down vote, but I am genuinely mystified as to how the documentation could have been in any way unclear on this topic.

Comment: Thanks. I edited it with quotes from `?prcomp` to be more explicit. The source code was honestly clearer than the help doc, which seems to be trying to describe two different things at the same time.

Comment: If you say so. Not sure how much clearer "the calculation is done by a SVD on the...data matrix, **not** by using eigen on the covariance matrix" could possibly be, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, luckily, can be found in the source codes of the two functions.

First, the source for `prcomp`:

```
> stats:::prcomp.default
function (x, retx = TRUE, center = TRUE, scale. = FALSE, tol = NULL, 
    ...) 
{
    x <- as.matrix(x)
    x <- scale(x, center = center, scale = scale.)
    cen <- attr(x, "scaled:center")
    sc <- attr(x, "scaled:scale")
    if (any(sc == 0)) 
        stop("cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance")
    s <- svd(x, nu = 0)
    s$d <- s$d/sqrt(max(1, nrow(x) - 1))
    if (!is.null(tol)) {
        rank <- sum(s$d > (s$d[1L] * tol))
        if (rank < ncol(x)) {
            s$v <- s$v[, 1L:rank, drop = FALSE]
            s$d <- s$d[1L:rank]
        }
    }
    dimnames(s$v) <- list(colnames(x), paste0("PC", seq_len(ncol(s$v))))
    r <- list(sdev = s$d, rotation = s$v, center = if (is.null(cen)) FALSE else cen, 
        scale = if (is.null(sc)) FALSE else sc)
    if (retx) 
        r$x <- x %*% s$v
    class(r) <- "prcomp"
    r
}
```

Notice that no covariance calculations are being performed in the upper block. The scaling and centering operations are performed on the input as provided, at which point the singular value decomposition (SVD) function is called on the result. The next step is to check the size of the result against the rank of the resulting diagonalization to ensure the result is valid. Lastly, the output is formatted and set to the appropriate class.

In other words, `prcomp` is a nice improvement to simply calling SVD on covariance matrices, but will not compute covariance matrices for you. <strike>`prcomp` is not called on data, it's called on some provided estimate of covariance *of* some data.</strike>

**edit:** The struck-out sentence is wrong! There is no need to form the covariance matrix in this case, which I would have realized had I had my math hat on properly! For an explanation why, see [this math.SO thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/what-is-the-intuitive-relationship-between-svd-and-pca). Calculating the principal components with SVD on the data matrix is definitely more efficient here.

Compare to the code from `princomp` (only a portion shown):

```
if (is.list(covmat)) {
    if (any(is.na(match(c("cov", "n.obs"), names(covmat))))) 
        stop("'covmat' is not a valid covariance list")
    cv <- covmat$cov
    n.obs <- covmat$n.obs
    cen <- covmat$center
}
else if (is.matrix(covmat)) {
    if (!missing(x)) 
        warning("both 'x' and 'covmat' were supplied: 'x' will be ignored")
    cv <- covmat
    n.obs <- NA
    cen <- NULL
}
else if (is.null(covmat)) {
    dn <- dim(z)
    if (dn[1L] < dn[2L]) 
        stop("'princomp' can only be used with more units than variables")
    covmat <- cov.wt(z)
    n.obs <- covmat$n.obs
    cv <- covmat$cov * (1 - 1/n.obs)
    cen <- covmat$center
}
```

As you can see, the `princomp` function does a lot more depending on how the input is passed, which requires more care.

Comment: nice one--pulled down the source answered the OP and provided a nice summary. +1 from me